# How to make a request to API by fetch js in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, fetch

I have a web server, which has API.I used Postman to create POST and Get requests, and all worked fine.
Now I've started to write a front-end app, and I cannot make a post request from browser. When I run index.html from my computer, I get this Error: "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows
reading the remote resource at https://localhost:3000/python. Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing".
Here is my code:

```
async function createRes(){
  try { const connect = await fetch ('http://127.0.0.1:3000/python',
    {method:"POST",
    body:JSON.stringify({date:"01/02/2019"}),
    headers:{"Content-Type":"application/json",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"
    }, 
    credentials:"include"})

    const data = await connect.json();
  } catch(error){
      console.log(error.message)} 
}
```

Comment: Hi Yuri, what are you using for your back-end? As others have suggested your back-end needs to have CORS enabled. It seems your using Python? So maybe something like this: https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: I use express (node.js)

Comment: Hello @Yuri Molodyko,
This happens very often locally.
I see you're on: https://localhost:3000/python
If you can do a test on an external server, it can work.
Can you do the test?
Have a good day and be brave!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Express please try:

```
npm install cors
```

Then, in your index.js file:

```
const app = express()
app.use(cors())
```

Comment: It works like that: app.use(cors( {credentials: true, origin: true}))

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure CORS on the web server hosting the API

Answer (score 1):

The problem does not lie in your front-end app, but on the server-side (your API). You have to configure your server to allow CORS requests from your app. Adding `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` header to the request will not change anything. More about CORS [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). There's nothing else I can write to help you, since you didn't provide any information about your API.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to enable CORS on the API you are running on localhost (http://localhost:3000/python).

Essentially moving the: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to your API rather than the client making the request.